# Testing a sever launching cli application - Python, Flask

Tags: python, testing, flask, python-unittest, python-click

**Question**
How to test a blocking cli application in Python?

**What I am trying to accomplish**

I have a `manage.py` file, which is used to start the flask development web server (and other admin stuff that are out of the scope of this question). Typically I would run this as `python manage.py runserver`, but for keeping this question simple and relevant I have edited that file  (see Minimal, Reproducible Example) to just run the server. So the below command works

```
$ python manage.py 
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production...
```

The issue comes with testing the functionality of this cli application. [Click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) has the [CliRunner.invoke()](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.testing.CliRunner.invoke), which allows one to test cli applications. But in this particular case, it fails as the server is already running.

```
from manage import runserver
from click.testing import CliRunner
import requests
import unittest


class TestManage(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_runserver(self):
        runner = CliRunner()
        runner.invoke(runserver)
        # It blocks above, does not go below!
        r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1')
        assert r.status_code == 200


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**Attempts at solution**

After trying many approaches I have found a "solution", which is to spawn a [Process](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class) to start the server, run the tests and then terminating the process on exit (this is included in the example). This feels more like a hack rather than a "real" solution.

**Minimal, Reproducible Example**

- *Folder structure*

  ```
  flask_app/
     - app.py
     - manage.py
     - test_manage.py
  ```
- *app.py*

  ```
  from flask import Flask

  app = Flask(__name__)


  @app.route('/')
  def hello():
      return 'Hello, World!'
  ```
- *manage.py*

  ```
  import click
  from app import app


  @click.command()
  def runserver():
      app.run()


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      runserver()
  ```
- *test_manage.py*

  ```
  from manage import runserver
  from multiprocessing import Process
  from click.testing import CliRunner
  import requests
  import unittest


  class TestManage(unittest.TestCase):

      def setUp(self):
          self.runner = CliRunner()
          self.server = Process(
              target=self.runner.invoke,
              args=(runserver, )
          )
          self.server.start()

      def test_runserver(self):
          r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1')
          assert r.status_code == 200

      def tearDown(self):
          self.server.terminate()


  if __name__ == '__main__':
      unittest.main()
  ```

And run the test using `$ python test_manage.py`.